# Wiping out DFS in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

How do I wipe out the DFS in Hadoop?

Answer (score 16):

You need to do two things:

1. Delete the main hadoop storage directory from every node. This directory is defined by the hadoop.tmp.dir property in your hdfs-site.xml.
2. Reformat the namenode:

```bsh
hadoop namenode -format
```

If you only do (2), it will only remove the metadata stored by the namenode, but won't get rid of all the temporary storage and datanode blocks.

Comment: deleting main hadoop storage directory from every single node is not feasible!

Comment: performing namenode -format will delete all the metadata and also makes your cluster unusable.  This is not a advisable option.

Comment: Also if a namenode -format will generate new cluster id for the namenode and all the other deamons will not be able to communicate with the namenode. Please update your answer to avoid misguidance. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
hdfs dfs -rm -r "/*"
```

(the old answer was deprecated)

Comment: I get a delete failed error when I try this, I can delete subdirectories, but not the root

Comment: `hdfs dfs -rmr` is now deprecated and also won't work for `/`. You should try `hdfs dfs -rm -r "/*"` instead.

Answer (score 10):

```
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

Comment: Watchout: existing old datanodes won't work with this newly formatted dfs.
See http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-107

Answer (score 3):

So this is what I have had to do in the past.

1. Navigate to your hadoop directory on your NameNode, then stop all the hadoop processes. By running the default stop-all script. This will also stop DFS. e.g.

```
cd myhadoopdirectory
bin/stop-all.sh
```

2. Now On every machine in your cluster (Namenodes, JobTrackers, datanodes etc.) delete all files in your main hadoop storage mine is set to the temp folder in the root folder. Yours can be found in the conf hdfs-site.xml file under hadoop.tmp.dir property e.g.

```
cd /temp/
rm -r *
```

3. Finally go back to your name node, and format it by going to your hadoop directory and running 'bin/hadoop namenode -format' e.g.

```
cd myhadoopdirectory
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

4. Start up your cluster again by running the following command. It will also startup DFS again.

```
bin/start-all.sh
```

5. And it should work.

Answer (score 3):

You may issue

```
hadoop fs -rmr /
```

This would delete all directories and sub-directories under DFS.

Another option is to stop your cluster and then issue:

```
hadoop namenode -format
```

This would erase all contents on DFS, and then start the cluster again.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to call `bin/stop-all.sh` to stop dfs and mapreduce.
2. Delete data dir which is configured in **conf/hdfs-site.xml** and **conf/mapred-site.xml**.
3. Make sure that you have deleted some temporary files existing in /tmp dir.

After all above steps, you can call `bin/hadoop namenode -format` to regenerate a dfs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop you cluster

   `${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/stop-mapred.sh`

   `${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/stop-dfs.sh`

   or if its pseudo distributed, simply issue:

   `${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/stop-all.sh`
2. Format your hdfs

   `hadoop namenode -format`