# My cloudera hdfs_data folder is full. How to clean it?

Tags: hdfs, cloudera, diskspace

My /hdfs_data/dfs/dn/current/ is full which is putting my machine in unhealthy state. I am using cloudera version 5.5.2. How should I clean it ?

Thanks;

Comment: try hdfs dfs -rmr <your-dir>

Comment: on this data node, I do not have hadoop native library, so the command hdfs dfs -rmr <your-dir> is not working

Comment: My question is how can I clean data from a datanode, currently my data node is dead and preventing to start cloudera. It is on File Systems, disk = "/dev/sdb" and Mount Point ="/hdfs_data"

Comment: refer this to decommision a datnode using cloudera manager http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-2-x/topics/cm_mc_decomm_host.html

Comment: @urug how Decommissioning and Recommissioning Hosts is going to help to solve my problem of full disk?

Comment: please clarify what you mean by dead data node? also what do you mean by "i don't have native hadoop library"? what kind of cluster is this. Please describe the cluster and specific problem

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem. If you don't care about the data on hdfs, then you can simply `rm -R /dfs/dn/current` on every datanode of your cluster and `hdfs namenode -format`, this will free up plenty of memory.

Also, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408318/wiping-out-dfs-in-hadoop).