# Hadoop/HDFS: Connection refused, all data nodes at 100%

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

Up until a few days ago I had a working Hadoop cluster. I copied over a very large data set and maxed out all of my datanodes. Running any sort of HDFS command gives me:

```
>hdfs dfs -ls
>ls: Call From hadoop-n2/XXX.XXX.XX.XX to hadoop-n2:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

So I can't go in a delete the files that are taking up space. I tried wiping HDFS clearn [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408318/wiping-out-dfs-in-hadoop) but I don't see any tmp property in hdfs-site.xml. I tried reducing the replication factor from 3 to 1 but that didn't seem to change anything.

I'm running Hadoop v2.6.0 with Cloudera CDH v5.6.0.

Comment: ssh keys might have changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28661285/hadoop-cluster-setup-java-net-connectexception-connection-refused

Comment: @JohnSimon Why would the ssh keys change? I'm able to ssh into any node from any other node.

Comment: Were you using Ambari? If so, I would have just added another datanode to the cluster to temporarily relieve the nodes.